# How to align dynamically created items to the right and one below the other in grid layout?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have this section which receives data dynamically.
I want the stars to appear under the hotel name and to look more compact with less space between them and I am not sure how to achieve this

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">
      Hotel Name:
   </div>
   <div class="col" th:text="*{getName()}"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">
      Hotel Category:
   </div>
   <div class="col float-right"
      th:each="star : ${#numbers.sequence(1, accommodationViewModel.category)}">
      <i class='bx bxs-star'></i>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is what they look like now:
[image]

I tried adding  `<div class="col-md-6">` and the result was this
[image]

Edit 1:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for my problem is:

```html
.col-1 {
flex: 0;
padding: 0;
margin-left: 2%;
}
```

[image]